# GraphQL skip after index

Tags: graphql

I'm trying to query and return a sorted list (ABC-sort on `title`) where all items above a specified limit, say 10, include all columns. For everything after that index, include only metadata like `id` and `title`. Is this possible in a single GQL query or do I need one query for full data and another for metadata only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to perform two queries. The shape of the response object cannot be dynamic. However you can do it with a single resolver and in a single network request:

```
query aQuery(limit: Int) {
  myQuery(limit: $limit) {
    id
    title
    field3
    field4
    …
  }
  myQuery {
    id
    title
  }
}
```

Where `myQuery` is defined in your schema as:

```
type Query {
  myQuery (limit: Int) [Book]
}
```

Your `myQuery` resolver needs to accept an *optional* limit argument.